# Cluster analysis within a set of integers

Tags: python, combinations, cluster-analysis

Sorry for the broad title, I just do not know how to name this.

I have a list of integers, let's say:

```
X = [20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 100]
```

And a second list of tuples of size 2 to 6 made from this integers:

```
Y = [(20, 30), (40, 50, 80, 100), (100, 100, 100), ...]
```

Some of the numbers come back quite often in `Y` and I'd like to identify the group of integers coming back often.

Right now, I'm counting the number of apparition of each integer. It gives me some information, but nothing about the groups.

Example:

```
Y = [(20, 40, 80), (30, 60, 80), (60, 80, 100), (60, 80, 100, 20), (40, 60, 80, 20, 100), ...]
```

On that example `(60, 80)` and `(60, 80, 100)` are combinations which come back often.

I could use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()` to generate every combinations and then count the number of apparition, but is there any other better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know if it is a strictly better way to do it or rather similar, but you could try to check for appearance fraction of subsets. Below a brute force way of doing so, storing the results in a dictionary. Quite possibly, it would be better to build a tree where you don't search through a branch if the appearance rate of its elements already did not make the cut. (i.e. if (20,80) does not appear together often enough, then why search for (20,80,100)?)

```
N=len(Y)
dicter = {}
for i in range(2,7):
    for comb in itertools.combinations(X,i):
        c3 = set(comb)
        d3 = sum([c3.issubset(set(val)) for val in Y])/N
        dicter['{}'.format(c3)] =  d3
```

As edit: you probably are not interested in all non-appearances, so I'll throw in a piece of code to chop down the final dictionary size..First we define a function to return a shallow copy of our dictionary with 1 value removed. This is required to avoid `RunTimeError` when looping over the `dict`.

```
def removekey(d, key):
    r = dict(d)
    del r[key]
    return r
```

Then we remove insignificant "clusters"

```
for d, v in dicter.items():
    if v < 0.1:
        dicter = removekey(dicter, d)
```

It will still be unsorted, as itertools and sets do not sort by themselves. Hope this will help you further along.

Comment: I'm going to look into it. From what you wrote, you seem to have perfectly understood the issue. I just need to understand the code now :) Thanks.

Comment: No problem. I am a little bit frustrated I can't come up with something elegant for the tree search though..hope you have more luck. :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm using spyder so sorting is not much of an issue with the visualization tool for the dict. I got what everything does. A few issues for my case because of my lack of precision, but it's great. Gonna work with this for now, and try to improve it and get my results. Thanks for pointing out the set, I had a hardtime working them out...

Answer (score 2):

The approach that you are looking for is called

### Frequent Itemset Mining

It finds frequent subsets, given a list of sets.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into it!